# AngularJS Custom Filter orderBy sortPredicate not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angular-filters, angularjs-orderby

The problem is that I have an array of recipe objects. Each recipe object has some comments on it. I want to sort the array in angularJS controller using the $filter service provided by angular.

```
 $scope.recipes = $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, function(recipe) {
    return recipe.comments.length;
  });
```

But its not giving the required results. However, I'm able to achieve the desired results using the JS array sort functionality like this

```
$scope.data.sort(function(a, b) {
     if (a.comments.length < b.comments.length) return 1;
     if (b.comments.length < a.comments.length) return -1;
     return 0;
    });
```

The Plunkr for the same scenario is : http://plnkr.co/edit/L9Bt67xHRCJLBoWG8EZp?p=preview

Thanks in advance. Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done a lot simpler using orderBy

http://plnkr.co/edit/B0fMi7FotgmG2tkCjySt?p=preview

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="r in recipes | orderBy:'-comments.length'">
     {{r.title}} - {{r.comments.length}}
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to do it in the controller only. Is there a way out for it too?

Comment: Ok, I'm with you. Then yes. I've added another answer - since both answers do the same thing other people might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Added this as another answer, since you want to manage it in your controller and you want the reverse, add `true` as the final arg in `$filter`

Documentation
`$filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)`

Example

```
$scope.recipes = $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, function(recipe) {
  return recipe.comments.length;
}, true);
```

I'm pretty sure you can also set the reverse to a var in scope if you wish.

Comment: Oh, It was working prior too. Silly me. Thanks Anyway. Actually, I should have displayed the counts along with the recipe titles.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.recipes = $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, "comments.length", true)
```

The filter expects an *expression*, not a function.

Comment: This is incorrect, it will accept both, it will also accept an array of functions too. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy